# selector with android:drawable="@color/transparent" attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable

```
<!--  Active tab -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
<!--  Inactive tab -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected" />
<!--  Pressed tab -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
```

is there a way to get the error in this kind of selector i want to use this kind o selector but i get an error in `android:drawable="@color/transparent` i get this error when i run it

[image]

i run out of ideas to do on make it work

Answer (score 39, accepted):

replace

```
android:drawable="@color/transparent"
```

with

```
android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
```

You should refer to the `android` namespace

Answer (score 6):

Try writing the line of code for transparency like this:

```
 <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:drawable="@color/transparent"
```

is not used in android framework by default. And if you want to need it you have to make manually. So you need change this from

```
android:drawable="@color/transparent"
```

to

```
android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `android:drawable` with `android:color` and put color code of the color here. i.e.`android:color="#00000000"`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code:

```
android:background="any color u want"
android:alpha=".6"
```

It'll give you a colour with tranparent background